# Like query on 2 columns

Tags: hibernate, hql

I would like to have a like query on 2 columns on 2 different tables.

Lets say Table Product and Table DefectProducts have columns of SerialNumber. I want my query work for like below case.

*For example SerialNumber from Product table is NS123 and SerialNumber from DefectProducts is SNS123. I want to get that SNS123 value.*

```
Original query: 
select dp.SerialNumber from Product p, DefectProducts dp where p.SerialNumber=dp.SerialNumber

Desired Query:
select dp.SerialNumber from Product p, DefectProducts dp where p.SerialNumber like %dp.SerialNumber%
```

Comment: This would require UNION but HQL does not support UNION. Either you have to create two queries or use SQL

Comment: Could you write the sql statement for doing with union?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A UNION with SQL would look like this

```
select SerialNumber from (
    select p.SerialNumber from Product p
    union all 
    select dp.SerialNumber from DefectProducts dp
) as x
where x.SerialNumber like = ?
```